# Rounding double to 2 decimal places returns always 0.0

Tags: java

I try to round a double value to 2 decimal places but I always get 0.0. I tried three approaches.

First:

```
System.out.println(Math.round(reward*100.0)/100.0);
```

Second:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(round(reward, 2))); 
private double round(double value, int places)      
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Third:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
System.out.println(df.format(reward));
```

Everytime I only get 0.0. Example values:

- 5.957818181818184E-16 0.0
- 3.927272727272729E-18 0.0
- 3.1250000000000005E-16 0.0
- 1.6000000000000006E-19 0.0

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want round? Do you want to print the result or use it in further calculations?

Comment: And: `6*10^-16` is `0.0000000000000006`, this should be `0.0` when rounded.

Comment: The value does not have to be exact. I need it for furthur calculations, with the printing here I simply want to show how I tested the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the examples you've quoted are very, very, very small numbers. If you round them to two places, the result is zero. That's why you're getting the results you're getting; they're correct. The negative exponent with [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) tells us that.

For instance, `2E-1` is `0.2`. You can write the number out, then move the decimal point to the left the number of times given in the exponent (it would be to the right if the exponent were positive). So your

```
5.957818181818184E-16
```

is really:

```
0.0000000000000005957818181818184
```

...which rounded to two places is `0.00`.

Answer (score 4):

The four values you are testing there **should** be rounded to 0.0!

`5.957818181818184E-16` equals `5.95... * 10^(-16)` equals `0.000...0595...` with 16 zeroes in front of the first non-zero digit. Similar for your other values. Are you familiar with the [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)?

Comment: 15 Zeros if you don't count the 0 before the decimal sign.

Comment: Good point, thanks. 15 zeroes after the decimal sign, so the 5 is the 16th digit after the decimal.